# Is it possible to use tornado's gen.engine and gen.Task with twisted?

Tags: python, asynchronous, client-server, twisted, tornado

The project I am working on is all written in Tornado, but I have included a bit of Twisted to deal with asynchronous XML-RPC. I was wondering if you can use Tornado's gen.engine and yield gen.Task with Twisted's code. Is this possible? If so how would the syntax look like? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - but it's called `inlineCallbacks` in Twisted:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks

@inlineCallbacks
def foo():
    x = yield bar()
    print x
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gen.Task` with anything that takes a `callback` keyword argument.  However, Twisted-style code usually returns a `Deferred` instead of taking a callback as input.  You'll need to wrap the `Deferred` in something `tornado.gen` can understand (probably a `Future`).  Something like this (untested):

```
def wrap_deferred(deferred):
    # Could also use concurrent.futures.Future from the standard library,
    # but Tornado's version gives better tracebacks on python 2.
    future = tornado.concurrent.TracebackFuture()
    deferred.addCallbacks(future.set_result, future.set_exception)
    return future

@gen.coroutine
def my_coroutine(self):
    # Use wrap_deferred instead of gen.Task
    x = yield wrap_deferred(some_twisted_function())
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified Ben's sample code a bit in order to set exception correctly.

```
def wrap_deferred(deferred):
    future = tornado.concurrent.TracebackFuture()
    deferred.addCallback(future.set_result)
    deferred.addErrback(lambda err: future.set_exception(err.value))
    return future
```

twisted wrap exception as a failure.Failure. future.set_exception complains it is not an exception type.