# Using Tornado and Twisted at the same time

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted, tornado

I am in a weird situation where I have to use Twisted in a system built completely out of Tornado.
They can share the same IOLoop so I know they can work together. My question is can I safely use their co-routine decorators in the same function? For example:

```
import tornado.platform.twisted
tornado.platform.twisted.install()

...

@gen.engine
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def get(self):

    ...

    a = yield gen.Task(getA) # tornado
    b = yield proxy.callRemote(getB) # twisted

    ...

    defer.returnValue(a + b) # twisted
```

They do work on the same IOLoop so I am thinking this should be fine. Would there be any unforeseen consequences? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this wouldn't work. In your case `inlineCallbacks` is wrapped directly around your generator and `gen.engine` is wrapped outside.  The problem is that `inlineCallbacks` does not know anything about `gen.Task` and it will yield it immediately (it has no way of passing it along to `gen.engine`).

To elaborate: if you yield `obj` inside an `inlineCallbacks`-wrapped generator, two things can happen:

1. `obj` is a `Deferred` in which case control is returned to the reactor until that `Deferred` fires.
2. `obj` is something else, in which case it is immediately sent back into your generator.

In your case, the result would be:

```
a = yield gen.Task(getA) # continues right through
# a is of type gen.Task here
b = yield proxy.callRemote(getB) # waits for result of proxy.callRemote
```

See [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-13.1.0/twisted/internet/defer.py#L1150) for how `inlineCallbacks` is implemented.

What is the right way to do this?  Try to use either `inlineCallbacks` or `gen.engine` (but not both).  Wrap the alien `gen.Task` (or `Deferred`) into the "native" form.  I am not familiar with Tornado but maybe [this question helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396711/is-it-possible-to-use-tornados-gen-engine-and-gen-task-with-twisted).

Alternatively, write your own decorator like `inlineCallbacks` that handles `gen.Task` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like what you want is [Cyclone](http://cyclone.io/), a web server framework for Python that implements the Tornado API as a Twisted protocol.