# Using Twisted's @inlineCallbacks with Tornado's @gen.engine

Tags: python, asynchronous, client-server, twisted, tornado

Tornado/Twisted newb here. First I just want to confirm what I know (please correct and elaborate if I am wrong):

In order to use @gen.engine and gen.Task in Tornado, I need to feed gen.Task() functions that are:

- asynchronous to begin with
- has the keyword argument "callback"
- calls the callback function at the very end

In other words the function should look something like this:

```
def function(arg1, arg2, ... , callback=None):

    # asynchronous stuff here ...

    callback()
```

And I would call it like this (trivial example):

```
@gen.engine
def coroutine_call():

    yield gen.Task(function, arg1, arg2)
```

Now I am in a weird situation where I have to use Twisted in a Tornado system for asynchronous client calls to a server (since Tornado apparently does not support it).

So I wrote a function in Twisted (e.g. connects to the server):

```
import tornado.platform.twisted
tornado.platform.twisted.install()
from twisted.web.xmlrpc import Proxy

class AsyncConnection():
    def __init__(self, hostname):
        self.proxy = Proxy(hostname)
        self.token = False

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def login(self, user, passwd, callback=None):
        """Login to server using given username and password"""

        self.token = yield self.proxy.callRemote('login', user, passwd) # twisted function
        callback()
```

And if I run it like so:

```
@gen.engine
def test():

    conn = AsyncConnection("192.168.11.11")
    yield gen.Task(conn.login, "user","pwd")
    print conn.token

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

And I DO get the token as I want. But my question is:

I know that Twisted and Tornado can share the same IOLoop. But am I allowed to do this (i.e. use @defer.inlineCallbacks function in gen.Task simply by giving it the callback keyword argument)? I seem to get the right result but is my way really running things asynchronously? Any complications/problems with the IOLoop this way?

I actually posted somewhat related questions on other threads

[Is it possible to use tornado's gen.engine and gen.Task with twisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396711/is-it-possible-to-use-tornados-gen-engine-and-gen-task-with-twisted)

[Using Tornado and Twisted at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502032/using-tornado-and-twisted-at-the-same-time)

and the answers told me that I should "wrap" the inlineCallback function. I was wondering if adding the callback keyword is enough to "wrap" the twisted function to be suitable for Tornado.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is mostly fine: adding a `callback` argument is enough to make a function usable with gen.Task.  The only tricky part is exception handling:  you'll need to run the callback from an `except` or `finally` block to ensure it always happens, and should probably return some sort of value to indicate whether the operation succeeded or not (exceptions do not reliably pass through a `gen.Task` when you're working with non-Tornado code)

The wrapper approach (which I posted in [Is it possible to use tornado's gen.engine and gen.Task with twisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396711/is-it-possible-to-use-tornados-gen-engine-and-gen-task-with-twisted)) has two advantages: it can be used with most Twisted code directly (since Twisted functions usually don't have a `callback` argument), and exceptions work more like you'd expect (an exception raised in the inner function will be propagated to the outer function).